# Group By Dynamic Ranges in SQL (cockroachdb/postgres)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, group-by, cockroachdb

I have a query that looks like

```
select s.session_id, array_agg(sp.value::int8 order by sp.value::int8) as timestamps
from sessions s join session_properties sp on sp.session_id = s.session_id
where s.user_id = '6f129b1c-43a6-4871-86f6-1749bfe1a5af' and sp.key in ('SleepTime', 'WakeupTime') and value != 'None' and value::int8 > 0 
group by s.session_id
```

The result would look like

```
f321c813-7927-47aa-88c3-b3250af34afa    | {1588499070,1588504354}
f38a8841-c402-433d-939d-194eca993bb6    | {1588187599,1588212803}
2befefaf-3b31-46c9-8416-263fa7b9309d    | {1589912247,1589935771}
3da64787-65cd-4305-b1ac-1393e2fb11a9    | {1589741569,1589768453}
537e69aa-c39d-484d-9108-2f2cd956d4ee    | {1588100398,1588129026}
5a9470ff-f930-491f-a57d-8c089e535d53    | {1589140368,1589165092}
```

The first column is a unique id and the second column is `from` and `to` timestamps.

Now I have a third table which has some timeseries data

```
records
------------------------
timestamp | name | value
```

Is it possible to find `avg(value)` from from records in group of session_ids over the `from` and `to` timestamps.

I could run a for loop in the application and do a union to get the desired result. But I was wondering if that is possible in `postgres` or `cockroachdb`

Comment: Yes. We are saving unix timestamps; The number of seconds since 1970

Comment: https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/epoch-mania/

Comment: Yes. The array will always have two values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't aggregate the two values but use two joins to find them. That way you can be sure which value belongs to which property.

Once you have that, you can join that result to your records table.

```
with ranges as (
  select s.session_id, st.value as from_value, wt.value as to_value
  from sessions s 
    join session_properties st on sp.session_id = s.session_id and st.key = 'SleepTime'
    join session_properties wt on wt.session_id = s.session_id and wt.key = 'WakeupTime'
  where s.user_id = '6f129b1c-43a6-4871-86f6-1749bfe1a5af' 
    and st.value != 'None' and wt.value::int8 > 0 
    and wt.value != 'None' and wt.value::int8 > 0 
)
select ra.session_id, avg(rc.value)
from records rc
  join ranges ra 
    on ra.from_value >= rc.timewstamp
   and rc.timestamp < ra.to_value
group by ra.session_id;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @a_horse_with_no_name it just worked like always :)
I would still go ahead check the time taken against building the queries in a for loop for the list of timestamps and doing unions. I may have follow up question.

Comment: @Mayank: btw: that's a horrible data model you have there

Comment: Let me try to justify. The important data that exists is in records table. The records table can have input from anywhere for e.g. sessions or non-session which may be just time-value series. The non-session data needs to belong to a session based on the range of timestamp but the data belongs to a user. There are more columns in records table one of which is user_id. That would modify the query like *`join ranges ra  on rc.user_id = ra.user_id and ra.from_... ra.to_value`* as sessions also has user_id. Do you find it equally horrible now as well? If yes I need help :)